# How do I interpolate the current user's id into the url section in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, interpolation

I'm trying to replace the '2' in the url field in the getEvents function and make it dynamic where it would grab the current user's id.

I wanted to do something like `${current_user.id}`. How do I go about it? like ideally this is what i want to do:

```
function getEvents() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/`${current_user.id}`/events',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data)
```

I have a current_user method in my ApplicationController file. I've tried applying json on it but I've gotten errors. 
Below is the entire code.

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :log_user_in #let these methods be used in views

  private
  def log_user_in
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def current_user #should return previous user or look for current user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

```html
$(function() {
  console.log('event.js is loaded...')
  listenForClick()
});

function listenForClick() {
  $('button#events-data').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    getEvents()
  })

  function getEvents() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/2/events',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data) {

    console.log("the data is: ", data)
    debugger
    let myEvent = new Event(data[0])
    let myEventHtml = myEvent.eventHTML()
    document.getElementById('ajax-events').innerHTML += myEventHTML
  })
}


class Event {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.id = obj.id
    this.name = obj.name
    this.host = obj.host
    this.description = obj.description
    // this.host.user.id = obj.user.id
  }
}


Event.prototype.newEventForm = function() {
   (`
  <strong>New Event</strong>
  <form>
    <input id='event-name' type='text' name='name'></input><br>
    <input type='text' name='description'></input><br>
    <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
  `)
};
```

Comment: it depends on template type,  try <% current_user.id >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to write: `${this.href}` in the url section.

Answer (score 0):

Add in view pass url from rails:
add something like (change path to correct):

`javascript_tag("window.UPDATE_URL = #{update_user_path(current_user)};")`

and in JS

```
  $.ajax({
    url: window.UPDATE_URL,
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, Igor. where exactly do I insert the javascript_tag code?

Comment: In layout, or your view

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post what you can do is:

1) Directly access the variable in the script tag

```
var user_id = <% current_user.id %>
```

2) Attach the id passed from controller to an element in the html body.

Then fetch the value of the id from the element to which it was set.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rohan. Sorry, I'm new to JS. for step 1 are you telling me to put that in the .html file? Can you break down what you mean in step 2?

I need to be able to make the current_user.id a dynamic input in the url:

 url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/(current_user id here)/events

that is a part of my ajax getEvents function

Comment: For Step 1, yes in html and inside script tag so that you can assign it to js variable and then can use it

Comment: For Step 2 , you can attach it to an html element say span and then can access that variable using javascript/jquery properties to get element data